# How to resume seeding a specific torrent after re-installing Windows?

Tags: windows, bittorrent

Assume we downloaded a torrent completely and seeded it for a while; now we're gonna re-install Windows and install the torrent client again. We also have downloaded files here too.

So, how could I resume seeding that torrent? We need our upload stats to be tracked as in the past to calculate the whole share ratio on the torrent site's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the torrent program again and point it at the torrent file and the downloaded files. it will resume seeding.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the "point to torrent file and downloaded files" Process?

Comment: It depends what client you're using. They all have a different procedure. Usually, it's sufficient to double-click on the torrent file and then, when it asks you where to download to, select the place the downloaded files are already.